# web3.js not working with React JS

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethereumjs, react

I have installed web3.js

```
npm install web3
```

my App.js

```
import React , {Component} from "react";
import web3 from "web3";
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider'  
import KryptoBird from "../abis/KryptoBird.json";

class App extends Component {

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>NFT MarketPlace </h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}



export default App;
```

but when I run

```
npm start
```

I am getting below error [[image: error after running react server][1]]

If I comment on the import statement of web3 in the App.js file it works fine.
I am having node version 16.

Any help will be appreciated !!! Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This is related to webpack setting.

if you are using create-react-app, I posted an answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70472965/web3-issue-react-application-not-compiling/70512623#70512623

If you are using webpack, here is related answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70559396/webpack-breaking-change

Answer (score 0):

**Web3 and Create-react-app**
If you are using create-react-app version >=5 you may run into issues building. This is because NodeJS polyfills are not included in the latest version of create-react-app.

Refer the Solution in the Below link

**https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js#troubleshooting-and-known-issues**

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using the new version of Webpack, I've fixed the problem with the poly-fill, you can see the complete implementation here :

https://github.com/EhsanParsania/React-Webpack5-Polyfill