# Web3.js package throws a lot of errors when importing in React app

Tags: web3js, react

When I try to import web3 package in my React app it throws a lot of errors saying there are missing modules.
I created the react app using the command -

```
npx create-react-app ./
```

Importing as

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

Just after this, the terminal has a lot of errors like

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream'

> ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 43:10-24
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url'.

Any solution to this?

Comment: What's the node version? How did you add web3 as dependency? Can you provide a link to the project repo?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117474/web3-js-not-working-with-react-js/117597#117597